# Java - Checking Colisions Between Multiple Rectangles in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, collision-detection, slick2d

After searching a large amount of sites, including this one, every solution i have came across seems to not work, or only work on the first object in the list.

**The Problem**

Slick2Ds Rectangle class offers many different methods for collision, one being the `intersects(Rectangle box);` method that correctly detects collisions when using this class in conjunction with javas built in ArrayList class,to an extent. The problem I'm having is that only the first object in the list is being detected and correctly collided upon.

The following code handles collisions:

```
public void move(float x, float y) {
    if (blocks.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++) {
            Rectangle r = blocks.get(i);
            Rectangle p = new Rectangle(xx + x, yy + y, 32, 32);
            if (!r.intersects(p)) {
                xp = xx;
                yp = yy;
                xx += x;
                yy += y;
                break;
            } else {
                xx = xp;
                yy = yp;
                xx += 0;
                yy += 0;
                System.out.println("Collide" + new Date());
                break;
            }
        }
    }else{
        xp = xx;
        yp = yy;
        xx += x;
        yy += y;
    }
}
```

*Key: xx = Player x; yy = Player y; xp = Players Last x Position; yp = Players Last y Position; r = Current Rectangle in the iteration list; p = Pre-calculated next position of the player*

This basic codes job is to add movement by simulating a rectangle that will be in the next position the player is. if it does not collide then the player wont collide and we can move, but if it does collide then we don't move the player as the next location is not open.

But the code has a flaw as at some point during the iteration only the **first** box  works, the others do detect collides but does not stop the box.

[Correct Collision; logged in the console to confirm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lcac.png)

[Incorrect Collision; not logged in the console, even though its another instance of the same object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLsPI.png)

Comment: Instead of printing _"Collide" + new Date()_, I would print the values of the two intersecting rectangles - that way you can see whether they should actually be intersecting or not.

Comment: i added a new logger for you guys to look at, to see if you can help me find my error

Comment: Why do both branches of the `r.intersects(p)` if statement break?

Comment: To not allow the code to add the movement in iterations , basically what it would do is after each iteration the speed would be multiplied exponentially. But I have found removing the break does not change the situation. Only making movement over a block slower.

Comment: Note that `ArrayList` is not important to the question or solution, any sort of `List` will act the same; indeed, any `Iterable` will also do if you use the [enhanced for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) like `for (final Rectangle r : blocks) { ... ` (and in Karl's answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you use :

```
public void move(float x, float y) {

    boolean intersectedBlock = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++) {
        Rectangle r = blocks.get(i);
        Rectangle p = new Rectangle(xx + x, yy + y, 32, 32);

        if (r.intersects(p)) {
            intersectedBlock = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (intersectedBlock) {
        xx = xp;
        yy = yp;
        xx += 0;
        yy += 0;
        System.out.println("Collide" + new Date());
    } else {
        xp = xx;
        yp = yy;
        xx += x;
        yy += y;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, I didn't think to do iteration and movement sepaeratly

Answer (score 0):

try to remove all the breaks.
because if it find the intersects or not, it will break out of the loop.

Comment: Done, although collisions are detected, stopping does not occur, it only slows the movement of the player. That is the unknown issue. Collisions are detected but are not handled as they should be. Another bug is that exponential player speed occurs relative to the size of the array list.

Comment: The speedup might be because you add the momentum to the player's position for every block that is not currently intersecting the player.   Your for loop loops through each block. If the player intersects it, it doesnt move. If the player doesn't, the player is moved.